# Are Microsoft's IE Images 64-bit or 32-bit?

Tags: internet-explorer, virtualization

Are Microsoft's [Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Images](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11575) 64-bit or 32-bit? For example, if I were to download the Windows Vista with IE7 image and then install IE9, would it be IE9 64-bit and 32-bit or just 32-bit by itself? You would think this information would be shown somewhere on Microsoft's site, but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since they are built for Microsoft Virtual PC as stated in the article, these would all be 32 bit only as Virtual PC only supports 32 bit guests.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it's a universal binary that contains both, but will install only the 32bit version if you're on a 32bit host. By default, Vista/Win7 will both start the 32bit version anyways, since most plugins (especially Flash, until v11 is actually released) have not made the jump to 64bit yet.

Comment: He's not talking about IE itself; he's talking about the Virtual PC .vhd's (VM hard drives) that contain Windows+IE. Since the OS is included, the question is whether the OS itself is 64-bit (and thus will have/install a 64-bit IE).

Comment: Not a universal binary, but it is an universal installer.  It poops both 32bit and 64bit DLLs in their respective places in the system directory.